# Disable click events for links while selecting text

Tags: html, hyperlink, selection

I have a div containing text within a link, like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de"><div>123456890</div></a>
```

This link should work if I click on it. But I also want to be able just to select the numbers so that I could copy them to clipboard.

How could I archive this on all links on my site?

(A nice addition would be if I could use double click for selection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can select a `link` if you select before and after it but you can not select part of linked text easily! because selecting a text is combination of `mousedown` and `mouseup`. but I got a solution for you that use `mouseenter` event to select text. something like this:

```js
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
   var doc = document;
   var element = this[0];
   console.log(this, element);
   if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
       var range = document.body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(element);
       range.select();
   } else if (window.getSelection) {
       var selection = window.getSelection();        
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNodeContents(element);
       selection.removeAllRanges();
       selection.addRange(range);
   }
};

$('a').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#target').selectText().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="target" href="http://www.google.de"><div>123456890</div></a>
```

*(mouse over on your text and then right click to copy then you can click on link!)*